# SignalR Server to Client only

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I setup `SignalR` in my application and it works very nice!

I have a Hub which is only supposed to push messages from the server to the client.

However, i can also call the method from the client back to the server, doing like this:

```
// this makes a call from the client to the server
$.connection.appplicationHub.server.productCreated();
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bad question.

To send messages from Server to Client, i don't need to create the method in the `Hub` class. Methods created in the `Hub` class are made for Client -> Server messages.